# Display a div if a checkbox is checked in reactive form with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to display a div if a my check box is checked. This my form :

```
 repairForm = new FormGroup({
  inftwoEuro : new FormControl(true),
  measurement : new FormControl('')
  })
```

HTML :

```
<form class="k-form k-form-inline " style="padding-top:7px; padding-left: 0px;"
            [formGroup]="repairForm">
            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding-left">
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="inftwoEuro" kendoCheckBox >
            </div>
            <div *ngIf ="inftwoEuro" class="col-md-12 no-padding-left">
              <input kendoTextBox class="k-textbox form-control"
               formControlName="measurement">
              </div>
        </form>
```

Here the div is always not displayed even the checkbox is checked or not I don't know why

Comment: Value true assign on global variable then after use *ngIf conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```js
<div *ngIf="repairForm.get('inftwoEuro').value" class="col-md-12 no-padding-left">
  <input kendoTextBox class="k-textbox form-control" formControlName="measurement">
</div>
```

Juste here a working StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3irrav?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Hi thanks for answering ! but it still not working !

Comment: @hibanebli I edited my post and added a StackBlitz, please check

Answer (score 0):

Ts File

```
inftwoEuro: any;
```

Inside  constructor

```
constructor() {
this.inftwoEuro = false;
}
```

```
this.inftwoEuro = true;
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf ="inftwoEuro" class="col-md-12 no-padding-left">
 <input kendoTextBox class="k-textbox form-control" formControlName="measurement">
</div>
```